# Draw circle with a radius in meter

Tags: arcgis-android-api

I need to draw a circle around a point with the ArcGis android sdk, but there is no Circle class only a Polygon. Now my idea was to use the polygon and calculate a number of points around a center point at a certain distance (in meter), but that turned out to be trickier than I thought.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the GeometryEngine [Buffer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#buffer(com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry,%20double)) options will do what you're looking for. You can find example code [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/3cfc823688fa107996bb37c4972e123ee886e967/java/buffer)